# Amazon RDS accessible only from same vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a postgresql instance on RDS that uses the default vpc and i want to
make it only accessible from that vpc.
If i launch an ecs task (fargate) on that vpc i want to get access to that posgresql else access denied for any other attempt.

Thank you

make amazon rds instance accessible only within the same vpc without going to the public internet. ( or other specific vpc if possible )

Comment: Set it to `Publicly Available = No`. Done!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein can I change that attribute after the creation of the instance ?

Comment: Yes. Choose the "Modify" option. It will require a restart of the database. Oops, I think it is called `Publicly Accessible`.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein thanks for the help but after creating an rds instance you can't change the publicly accessible option I didn't find it when i tried to modify the instance config so I assume that I need to change the subnet group associated to that instance and create some security groups ...

Comment: This might help, but there is conflicting advice: [How do I change the publicly accessible option for Amazon RDS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22866490/174777)