# EC2 instance can't connect to RDS, from same VPC/Subnet

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, rds

I have one EC2 instance that can connect to RDS, and another that can't.

- They are in the same VPC/Subnet/AZ
- They have the same IAM role
- They have different (but similar) security groups, both allow all inbound
- The subnets are showing in the configuration for the RDS instance
- The ec2 instance that can't connect just times out

What could be going wrong? Is there any way to work out where the connection is failing?

Comment: The security groups allow *all* inbound?  And you left the outbound rules alone (I hope)?  And you left the VPC Network ACLs alone, at their defaults?  And if you type `dig the-rds-hostname +short` you get a private IP in response, and that IP is on the same subnet?

Comment: Check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158216/what-would-prevent-me-from-connecting-to-a-mysql-server-on-aws-rds-from-an-aws-e/41711490#41711490

Comment: Could you please show your RDS Inbound security group and both of the EC2 outbound security groups? (Just Edit your question to include them.)