# How do I maintain a reliable connection to a RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, ipv4

I set up a MySQL DB on AWS RDS expecting to allow connections from my local machine as well as other machines in our team of developers. I could not find the way to establish a reliable connection to it for my team.

I followed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60976842/20442594) and successfully allowed connections from all the machines mentioned when I first set up the DB.

However, the IP address at [AWS Check IP](http://checkip.amazonaws.com/) changed overnight and we could not connect to the DB the following day. I tried using the static IPv4 address in the Wi-Fi settings but to no avail. I had to manually collect all IP's of every machine again.

Edit: I found out that you can follow these steps:

1. Contact your ISP and ask about static IP address options.
2. If available, request a static IP address for your internet connection.
3. Update RDS security group settings to allow inbound traffic from the new static IP address.

This way, you can establish a more stable connection. If static IP isn't an option, you'll have to cope with dynamic IP addresses and update the RDS settings when your IP changes.

Comment: I think you are talking about the Client Machines changing their IP address, am I right? If so you will have to configure each client machine to use a staic IP Address. Then configure the database once more with each static ip address of all the clients